# How to create an extension for SequenceOf in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

Generic arguments are not allowed in Swift extensions, something like

```
public extension SequenceOf<T>{
  ...
}
```

is not possible. Using something like

```
 public extension SequenceOf{

   public func Something<T>(){
   ....
   }

 }
```

leads to

*Extension of generic type 'SequenceOf' from a different module cannot provide public declarations*

So, how does one extend SequenceOf (or similar types) with extra methods?

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is not that your are extending `SequenceOf` but that you are doing it in a different module (i.e. a library or a framework).

Add the source file containing the extension to the project that is using it.

Comment: The error appears also if you put the extension in a standard app, say next to a view controller class in a single-view project. Or did you mean something else?

Comment: What if you drop the `public` modifier?

Comment: Come on, stop guessing. Nope, dropping the public modifier does not change anything.

Comment: I'm not guessing, for me it's working without the `public` modifier (on both method and extension)

Comment: You are right but it's not much of an extension if one has to copy the extension class all over the place, ie. in every file in which it's being used.

Comment: I agree, it's a know limit with Swift that will hopefully be lifted in the next releases.